# How to display contents of a 2-D javaScript Array into HTML Table?

Tags: javascript, html

JavaScript Code :
This code has to display two values on each row from result array

Problem : Displays all values in a line

```
 var tablecontent = '<tr>';
 for ( var i=0 ; i<pos; i++)
 {
 tablecontent += "<td>"+result[pos][0]+"</td><td>"+result[pos][1]+"</td>";
 }
 tablecontent = '</tr>';
 test.innerHTML += tablecontent;
```

HTML Code :

```
<div id="test">
<table> 
    <th> 
      <td>Column 1</td>
      <td>Column 2</td>
    </th>
</table>
```

Comment: I can't find in your script what the `result` and  `pos`  is

Comment: Result is 2-d array . pos is index.

Answer (score 0):

Here [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r1gjz9gm/). You have 2D array...

```
var data = [
    [1, 2],
    [3, 4],
    [5, 6],
    [7, 8],
    [9, 10],
    [11, 12]
];
```

and then loop through each cell and append cell data to `var tr;` variable...

```
for(var i in data){
    var tr;
    for(var j in data[i]){
        console.log(data[i][j]);
        tr += '<td>'+data[i][j]+'</td>';
    }
    tr = '<tr>'+tr+'</tr>';
    $('#table tbody').html(tr);
}
```

Last line `$('#table tbody').html(tr);` is using Jquery, but you can replace it with standard JavaScript code.